# Which JDK version do I need for Android development? (Command Line Tool)

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, java-8

Today I wanted to install on a new computer the Android SDK with the "Command Line Tool" from the official site.
As I remember Android SDK only supports Java 8. Now I noticed Java 8 is dead since January (eol).

So **what should I do, if I want to install the Android SDK without Android Studio and being a private person that doesn't own an Oracle (business) account?** (which you need if you want to download eol jdk's)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an old JDK from Oracle but as you pointed out its only available with a licence: [JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
And you can always use the OpenJDK: [Open JDK (Every Java Version)](https://openjdk.java.net/install/)

Comment: Yes, I tried the OpenJDK already. I need it for Windows so I downloaded it from here: [Java SE 8 JDK](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8). But if I start the sdkmanager.bat, it cant grab the source lists and throws a java SSL error. `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty Failed to download any source lists!`
I read that it could be a problem with the ca certs file because the jdk version is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

https://adoptopenjdk.net currently supports all distributions of JDK from version 8 onwards.
For example
https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html#x64_win

Here's an example of how I was able to use JDK version 8 with sdkmanager and much more:
https://travis-ci.com/mmcc007/screenshots/builds/109365628